# Unable to install pyspark in Jupyter note book

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have installed Python and Anaconda successfully, but while configuring pyspark I am facing issues.

```
Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan 8 2020, 20:23:39) 
[MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32 
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
20/05/24 13:33:48 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable 

Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties 
Setting default log level to "WARN". 
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel). 

Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.0.0-preview2
      /_/
Using Python version 3.7.6 (default, Jan 8 2020 20:23:39) 
SparkSession available as 'spark'. 

>>> 20/05/24 13:34:05 WARN ProcfsMetricsGetter: Exception when trying to compute pagesize, as a result reporting of ProcessTree metrics is stopped.
```

Can anyone help me with this or provide me the blog for configuring the pyspark for Jupyter notebook.

Comment: If I may provide an alternative, you can use Google Colab to execute your PySpark job. It's free and gives you access to a GPU as well. You can check my guide on how to use it and set up PySpark [here](https://jacobcelestine.com/knowledge_repo/colab_and_pyspark/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the below environment variable in windows

PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS as notebook

PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON as  jupyter

once these environment variables are set, then when you type pyspark in cmd it will directly open the jupyter notebook with pyspark configured.